# Linking one table column to another table in MYSQL and filling the column data in table automatically

Tags: mysql

I have two tables namely 'products' and 'seller'. products will have two columns 'product' and 'seller_id'. where the seller_id will be from the seller table(i.e. id of seller).
I have tried following code :

```
ALTER TABLE products
ADD FOREIGN KEY (seller_id) REFERENCES sellers(seller_id);
```

and the ouyput is :

```
id  product seller_id
1   product2    NULL
2   product2    NULL
3   product2    NULL
```

i want to just enter the product in product table and want to change the seller_id automatically according to the product that seller sells (in seller table i have a product column that specifies the product that seller sells.).for example if i enter product2 in my product table then it should go to seller table search for the seller that sells product2 and add his id to the seller_id column in product table. How can i do that? 
I am a total beginer so please correct me if I am doing anything wrong. And thanks in advance. :D

Comment: Foreign keys are for referential integrity - they don't grab updates or inserts from another table for that you need a trigger(s) on the table which is supposed to spawn updates or inserts to another table.Here's the syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html internet search triggers for concept.

Comment: Thank you. I will look for this.